# In Google App Engine should I not use instance methods in models?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Every time I've seen someone write a model with methods, they use class methods. I assumed this was the way things had to be done, but decided to test my code with instance methods first. I had no problems with using instance methods in my model, but now I'm wondering why everyone always seems to use class methods instead of instance methods. Is there some advantage to using class methods in GAE Models? And will I run into problems down the line if I'm using instance methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use instance methods when you need an instance of an entity to do something.

You normally use classmethods when you only need the model and you don't need or have the entity.

So for example you have a query for a specific set of instances that you use all the time, it makes sense to define it as classmethod.

e.g.

```
@classmethod
def do_somespecial_query(cls):
    return cls.query().filter(cls.some_property = True)
```

or if you need a factory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's completely fine to use instance methods for your custom ndb.Model class.

A lot of times, it helps the readability of your code.

I can't think of a huge drawback of using instance methods as of now

For example,

```
modelInstance.key
```

is an instance method that is very frequently used.

If it were

```
modelClass.key(instance)
```

if would significantly lower the readability of your code right? 
(This of course can depend heavily on your coding style)